# Animatied Sci Fi, aired in mid 80's on Nickelodeon channel in USA; actual movie may be European

Tags: story-identification, aliens, robots

This film has been on eating at my brain for quote some time. Hope someone can help.

The story was fit for kids, but also epic in scope. It involved a group of main characters that was caught in the middle of tension between the human faction, and a newly discovered alien faction of living machines. They had a fleet of green ships that would join together and fire a powerful lazer capable of massive destruction.

There was a Merlin/ Obiwan type of sage that had a long white beard down to his toes. In the end, he 'disappeared' into the ether, instead of dying.

The Robotic alien fleet destroys the human fleet, but the humans are saved when a massive supernova swallows the Robot's fleet in its entirety.

This may have been a European animated movie that was dubbed in English. Or not.

Comment: If Roy had a beard, that would track remarkably well to the Macross portion of Robotech.